# Gradle Compilation Error with Kotlin DSL configuring Java Spec

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm attempting to create a build file for a Kotlin project that will sometimes include java sources.  In the past with the Groovy based build files in a multi-project build, I could specify the `sourceCompatibility` in the `subproject` block with no issue.  With the Kotlin DSL I know it must be in the `java` block to configure with the Kotlin DSL, but when I attempt to do that from the `subproject` block in my root `build.gradle.kts` file I get a compilation error:

```
Script compilation errors:

Line 14:     java {
           ^ Expression 'java' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found

Line 14:     java {
           ^ Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
               public val PluginDependenciesSpec.java: PluginDependencySpec defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl

Line 15:         sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
               ^ Unresolved reference: sourceCompatibility

3 errors
```

I've included a [gist](https://gist.github.com/rpmoore/fee166cfff7e6931afe4ccdb5513303c) to the gradle build file I'm using.  Now I can get it working if I specify the java block in one of the subprojects `build.gradle.kts` files, but I want the setting applied to all of the subprojects, not just specific projects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use

```
configure<JavaPluginExtension> { ... }
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick!  Out of curiosity though, why doesn't my initial approach work?

Comment: The `java` method only exists in the sub projects because the root project is evaluated first, gradle sees that the sub projects use the Java plugin, and generates these extension methods before evaluating the sub projects. But when the root project is evaluated, Gradle doesn't know yet that sub projects use the Java plugin, and you thus don't have the java method available yet.